# Passing parameters to Action.OpenUrl button within adaptive card in MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm struggeling with Adaptive Cards in Microsoft Teams. Displaying of the card works, but I can't seem to get the action button to work. What I'd like to do is passing a parameter to an URL. The parameter value should be the value that the user entered in the text field named "nameInput". For example "Alice" which should open the URL "https://www.google.de/search?q=Alice". Somehow the button doesn't seem to work in MS Teams. This one is givin me headaches... Is it even possible?

"https://www.google.de/search?q={{nameInput.value}}" and ""https://www.google.de/search?q=${nameInput.value}" don't work either... :-(

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "contentUrl": null,
            "content": {
                "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "version": "1.3",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Testcard",
                        "size": "Medium",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "wrap": "true"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Input.Text",
                        "id": "nameInput",
                        "placeholder": "Type your name"
                    }
                ],
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                        "title": "OK",
                        "url": "https://www.google.de/search?q={nameInput.value}"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: We are able to repro this issue. We are checking this internally, we will update you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario is not supported with adaptive card. Passing parameter supports to bot with submit action.

Alternatively you can create a task module with html input and submit the task module to get back the response

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules

Comment: Thanks for the information and the hint with the task modules. I didnt't know about those. I will look into that.